# Fast api add all parameters to Json Payload

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I need to add all parameters to the api as part of Json Payload.
Working on an api I figured creating classes put them as part of Json Payload.

How can I add the rest of them to the Payload (Request Body), do I need to create a class for each `str` type ?

```
@router.post(path='/content-relevancy-interface/submit')
def content_relevancy_get_records(site_name: str, locale: str, lob: str, page_type: str, origins: OriginList = None,
                                      destinations: DestinationList = None,
                                      optimisation_opportunity: Union[str, None] = None,
                                      filter: FilterList = None):
```

[image]

Comment: You have to explicitly say that they're expected as part of the body - either create a single request class that contains all the expected fields (with the `destinations` and `origins` fields - `class ContentRelevacyRequest(BaseModel): site_name: str, lob: str, ...., origins: OriginsList = None, ...`), or explicitly say that the parameters are expected as part of the body: 
`site_name: Annotated[str, Body()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to explicitly declare that you want each parameter as body parameter, like so;

```py
from fastapi import Body
from typing_extensions import Annotated


@router.post(path='/content-relevancy-interface/submit')
def content_relevancy_get_records(site_name: Annotated[str, Body()], ...):
    pass
```

But a much cleaner and easier way is instead of using query parameters, using a schema.

```py
From pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Union


class RecordsGet(BaseModel):
    site_name: str
    locale: str
    lob: str
    page_type: str
    origins: OriginList = None
    destinations: DestinationList = None
    optimisation_opportunity: Union[str, None] = None
    filter_: FilterList = None
```

Then you can simply write the route like this;

```py
@router.post(path='/content-relevancy-interface/submit')
def content_relevancy_get_records(records_get: RecordsGet):
    pass
```

Then you can access the contents of the payload like `records_get.locale` and so on.
As I did, it'd be better to change the name `filter` to something else as it is the name of an in-built function.

Answer (score 1):

Create a pydantic model and pass that in args

```
class ContentRelevancyRequest(Basemodel):
    site_name: str
    locale: str
    lob: str
    page_type: str
    origins: OriginList = None
    destinations: DestinationList = None
    optimisation_opportunity: Union[str, None] = None
    filter: FilterList = None


@router.post(path='/content-relevancy-interface/submit')
async def content_relevancy_get_records(request_body: ContentRelevancyRequest = ContentRelevancyRequest()):
    # do_something
```

Also, You can perform directly using Body(), in this you don't need to specify json, the request can have any kind of JSON in it.

```
from fastapi import Body

@router.post(path='/content-relevancy-interface/submit')
async def content_relevancy_get_records(request_body: dict = Body()):
    # do something
```